# Navbar não muda o conteúdo

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Como fazer para a `navbar` do *Bootstrap 4.1* variar entre os conteúdos quando clicado neles, criei a `nav` seguindo o exemplo do site.

Para `navbar` abrir os itens dela precisa adicionar ação com js nela? Como faço?

Tentei assim:

```
$('#nav-home').on('hide.bs.tab', function (e) {
            e.target // newly activated tab
            e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
          });
$('#nav-perfil').on('hide.bs.tab', function (e) {
            e.target // newly activated tab
            e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
          });
```

Navbars:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap?

Comment: Vc que construir um Menu, ou um sistema de Tabs que troca o conteúdo, tipo isso: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs

Comment: Sistema de tabs, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

Comment: Cara postei uma resposta, qq dúvida comenta lá, e seu eu tiver entendido errado me fala que eu posso remover a resposta beleza

Comment: Qual a versão do jQuery que está usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas se vc que apenas um Sistema de TABs basta vc utilizar o componente que está na documentação. Repare que não é preciso JS adicional, mas é preciso que vc indexe na sua página todos os arquivos `.JS` que o componente precisa e o *framework* necessita. São eles o `jQuery`, o `Popper` e o `Bootstrap.js`

Repare na ordem que os arquivos `.JS` estão. Isso é essencial para o correto funcionamento do componente, se vc trocar essa ordem não vai funcionar.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home"
            aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile"
            aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact"
            aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">123</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">345</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">789</div>
</div>
    
<!-- ordem dos scripts deve ser essa -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- qualquer outro arquivo .js deve vir apos estes acima -->
```

Comment: Deu mais ou menos, quando eu clico entre os 2, o selecionado muda só não o conteúdo. Inicialmente mostra o 123, porém quando eu mudo para o Profile continua no 123.

Comment: @JoãoMiguel se aqui funcionou a única explicação é que vc deve ter feito algo ai que interferiu no funcionamento do componente. Verifique se vc removeu esse Java Script desnecessário, ou verifique se vc colocou alguma classe CSS que esteja interferindo nesse conteúdo das tabs, tipo displays ou positions no conteúdo das abas...